# Get unrelated entities in one trip to the database

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 entities that are not related to each other and I want to get all these entities in one trip to the database how can I do this ??

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more information?  What exactly are you trying to do, and why/how do you need the data back in this format?

Comment: Whay would you even want to do it? If you think that it will improve performance, it won't.

Comment: Actually, I just want to get the main entity back that has the main information, and get the other two entities too that have like general information that I have to show them to  the end users,so I don't want to do more than one trip to the database to get all the three entities.

Comment: That sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: If they are 3 unrelated entities, is there really something to optimize? I think it is definitely wrong wayo to go.

Comment: I would have thought that there must be a table that relates all of that information. Why not create the relation if you can make use of it? What are these entities of which you speak?

Comment: Thanks for the discussion,but my question is about the way that I can get the unrelated entities in one trip to the database using Entity framework ??
And for whatever reason these entities are not related this is not important to my now  ??

Comment: @kathy, nobody said you *couldn't.* We said you probably *shouldn't.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
 var result = from foo in ctx.Foos
              from bar in ctx.Bars
              where foo.id == xxx && bar.id == yyy
              select new { Foo = foo, Bar = bar};
```

This will fetch you a specific foo and a bar in the same query.
Although, this will generate some pretty inefficient SQL so I wouldn't recomend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Future Query extension method. This [link](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) can do the job as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving data from a pure relational database, you should look to see if you can retrieve multiple result sets in a single query. Alternately, if you can fetch ragged results, retrieve these in a tree structure with the corresponding shape.

If your connection to the database is not smart enough for this, you could use a universal join of the results and then return a union query tagged in some form to identify which result is from which table.

You don't state the reason for the reduced round-tripping, but you may also be able to use something like a stored procedure to collect the required data at the server and then return it in one result set.